# Sourcemaps for production

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am building a Javascript web application and using grunt to Uglify the JS. The question I have is about Sourcemaps. Is there any recommended practice for turning on / off sourcemap for production. My project is NOT open source. I am thinking - should I use sourcemap for dev and testing phase and turn it off for production to ensure that the users of my app don't get to see my code / understand what is going on behind the scenes? Is this a genuine concern or am I just worrying to much without reason?

The reason for this question is that most places that talk about sourcemap say that its purpose is to debug code in production.

Comment: i personally think it should be off on prod. we have a secret url param that adds the source-map comment to the JS file when needed; shhh.

Comment: I agree with @dandavis, your production code should be as free as possible from debug statements and files. Turn source maps off in production. As for whether or not users can see what is going on behind the scenes: Removing source maps does not make your code safer. It makes it more obscure but security through obscurity is never a good thing. If security is an issue, make sure a user cannot possible change requests/mess with your code to do something he or she shouldn't.